# How to store thumbnails in the same folder with Django ImageKit?

Tags: django, django-imagekit

Does anyone have experience using [ImageKit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit) to manage thumbnails?

I currently have the following in my **models.py**:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    image = ProcessedImageField(
        upload_to=image_upload,
        blank=True,
        validators=[validate_image],
        format='JPEG',
        help_text="Max file size is 3 MB."
    )
    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(
        source='image',
        processors=[ResizeToFill(50, 50)],
        format='JPEG',
        options={'quality': 60}
    )
```

I'd like to rename the thumbnail and store it in a particular folder (not the *CACHE/images/* folder that ImageKit defaults to), but can't figure out how to do that (and adding an "upload_to" to the thumbnail gives me an error). All help greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#defining-specs-in-models):

> ImageSpecFields, on the other hand, are virtual—they add no fields to your database and don’t require a database. This is handy for a lot of reasons, but it means that the path to the image file needs to be programmatically constructed based on the source image and the spec.

You might just want to stick to the ProcessedImageFIeld if you don't want your files to be stored in a cache folder.

Comment: Oh interesting, thank you! Are you aware of how to create a thumbnail based on the image uploaded into a separate field? I'm inclined to just run a `post_save` method and manually make one?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that question as I only took a quick dip into imagekit before moving out.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings file, if you set:

```
IMAGEKIT_CACHEFILE_DIR = ""
```

then the images will be saved in a subfolder of the same folder the original image is in. This instead of storing it in a /CACHE/images/ folder.